# Capacitor Camera throwing "Unable to create photo on disk" on Android 5

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

The capacitor camera plugin works great on Android 8+ devices, but for some reason, it throws the below error on a Samsung Tab A(SM-T280) running on Android 5.

**Configuration**

```
const image = await Plugins.Camera.getPhoto({
  quality: 100,
  allowEditing: false,
  resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
  source: CameraSource.Camera
});
```

**Error**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused because the directory is not created.

The fix to this is to add `storageDir.mkdirs();` after [this code](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/blob/master/android/capacitor/src/main/java/com/getcapacitor/plugin/camera/CameraUtils.java#L29) in the repo. The answer is referenced from [cordova-camera-plugin code](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/src/android/CameraLauncher.java#L610)

This issue is resolved in [Pull Request #2016](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/pull/2016)

Comment: Tried it. No luck. @capacitor/camera@1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Finally figure out, you need to add the below to android/app/src/main/res/xml/file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-path name="my_images" path="." />
        <cache-path name="my_cache_images" path="." />
        <files-path name="files" path="." />
    </paths>
```